# Line space in beamer

Tags: beamer, line-spacing

Consider this example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  line 1

  line 2
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

with the output:

[image]

How can I automatically control the line space between lines (insert more space of a predefined amount)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\linespread{1.5}\selectfont % <---
%\renewcommand\baselinestretch{1.5}\selectfont % <--- alternatively

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  line 1

  line 2
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```